# Prolog get elements in different lists with BFS

Tags: list, tree, prolog, breadth-first-search

i'm new at prolog and to improve my skills i'm trying to make some exercise.
At the moment I'm stuck with a BFS, let assume the tree is something like this:

```
[tree(tree(tree(nil,b,nil),a,tree(tree(nil,d,nil),c,tree(nil,e,nil)))]
```

after my query i've something like

```
X=a;

X=b;

X=c;

X=d;

X=e;
```

or, at least:

```
X=a,b,c,d,e;
```

I'm wondering about how to have results ordered by depth levels as output, something like:

```
X=[a];

X=[b,c];

X=[d,e];
```

or, in the best case, something like:

```
X=[ [a] , [b,c] , [d,e] ];
```

Help!

Comment: thx to Tim Cooper for correct my post, i'm pretty noob ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution, this time O(n).  It's still a bit ugly because I separated the actual BFS from the solution processing, but that should do it.

```
bfs2( Tree, Result ) :-
    bfs_queue( [[Tree, 0]], Queue ),
    queue_to_result( Queue, Result ).
bfs_queue( [], [] ) :- !.
bfs_queue( [[[],_]|Rest], RestResult ) :-
    !, bfs_queue( Rest, RestResult ).
bfs_queue( [[[Element, Left, Right], Level]|Rest], [[Element,Level]|RestResult] ) :-
    NextLevel is Level + 1,
    append( Rest, [[Left, NextLevel], [Right, NextLevel]], NewQueue ), !,
    bfs_queue( NewQueue, RestResult ).

process_level( [[Item, Level]|Rest], Level, [Item|RestResult], OutOfLevel ) :-
    !, process_level( Rest, Level, RestResult, OutOfLevel ).
process_level( OutOfLevel, _, [], OutOfLevel ) :- !.
queue_to_result( Queue, Result ) :-
    !, queue_to_result( Queue, 0, Result ).
queue_to_result( [], _, [] ) :- !.
queue_to_result( Queue, Level, [Current|Result] ) :-
    !, process_level( Queue, Level, Current, NewQueue ),
    NewLevel is Level + 1,
    queue_to_result( NewQueue, NewLevel, Result ).
```

Again, I represented trees as three element lists.

Comment: thanks!! It works!! I'm studying from "Learn Prolog Now", but i think it's a bit too simple. What's other book to study from?

Comment: This version performs significantly worse than bfs/2. I tested it with: n_tree(0, []) :- !.
n_tree(N0, [N0,Left,Right]) :- N1 is N0 - 1, n_tree(N1, Left), n_tree(N1, Right). and the query: ?- between(0, 20, N), n_tree(N, T), time(bfs(T,Nodes)), false. with both versions.

Comment: The constant is a lot higher with this one, because it generates the intermediate list of lists.  Additionally, the bfs/2 one gets much worse as the tree gets bigger; in processing level n, it must traverse levels 0 through n - 1, and it doesn't save any intermediates.  Hence the O(n^2).

Comment: @RobCos Bro can you please provide me the query that needs to run this example. I've tried and failed. I tried this
 ?- bfs2(tree(tree(nil,b,nil),a,tree(tree(nil,d,nil),c,tree(nil,e,nil))),X).
I'm new to prolog.So can't find out what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it's not particularly efficient.  I implemented the tree as a bunch of three element lists, like [Element, Left, Right], but it should work the same.

```
% returns a list of nodes at the given level of the tree
level( [], _, [] ).
level( [Element, _, _], 0, [Element] ) :- !.
level( [_, Left, Right], N, Result ) :-
    NewN is N - 1,
    level( Left, NewN, LeftResult ),
    level( Right, NewN, RightResult ),
    append( LeftResult, RightResult, Result ).

% does a bfs, returning a list of lists, where each inner list
% is the nodes at a given level
bfs( Tree, Result ) :-
    level( Tree, 0, FirstLevel ), !,
    bfs( Tree, 1, FirstLevel, [], BFSReverse ),
    reverse( BFSReverse, Result ).
bfs( _, _, [], Accum, Accum ) :- !.
bfs( Tree, Num, LastLevel, Accum, Result ) :-
    level( Tree, Num, CurrentLevel ), !,
    NewNum is Num + 1,
    bfs( Tree, NewNum, CurrentLevel, [LastLevel|Accum], Result ).
```

It should be possible to do this in O(n), but this is O(n^2).  I started to work on another solution that returns the level of each element in O(n), but I'm not sure how to transform that list to the solution format in O(n) without resorting to assert/retract.